# How to merge two ARM template JSON parameters files with override of duplicate parameters?

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-bicep

Imagine we have this simplified Azure bicep template, with these parameters we want to modify on a per-company and
per-environment basis, where we may have dozens of companies and say 4 - 6 environments each. I don't want to put all
parameters in each permutation, when ideally, most companies will use the defaults in the template, and only override
their companyName for all environments, and in NonProduction, maybe only override the environmentName and environmentSize.

**/path/to/baseline/deployments/test-template.bicep**

```
param companyName string                  // No default - Specify in common.parameters.json
param environmentName string = 'Sandbox'  // Override in both common.parameters.json as 'Production'; in development.parameters.json as 'Development'
param environmentSize string = 'Large'    // Override in only development.parameters.json as 'Small'
param outputFormat string = 'JSON'        // No need to overide

output companyName string = companyName
output environmentName string = environmentName
output environmentSize string = environmentSize
output outputFormat string = outputFormat
```

By convention, we have a common set of parameters which have values appropriate to Production but also meant to be shared
by all other environments - UNLESS - we want that environment to have a different value. So, for each NonProduction
environment, we have a subset of the parameters which are different than Production. Such as these two examples.

**/path/to/company-a/conf/common.parameters.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "companyName": {
      "value": "CompanyA"
    },
    "environmentName": {
      "value": "Production"
    }
  }
}
```

**/path/to/company-a/conf/development.parameters.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "comments": "Development Parameters.",
  },
  "parameters": {
    "environmentName": {
      "value": "Development"
    },
    "environmentSize": {
      "value": "Small"
    }
  }
}
```

Using the Azure CLI, I can then deploy this template to Production with this command. Note here we are specifying one
parameters file, so any parameter defined would override the default in the template, if specified.

```bash
az deployment group create --name MyProductionDeployment \
                           --resource-group MyProductionResourceGroup \
                           --template-file /path/to/baseline/deployments/test-template.bicep \
                           --parameters @/path/to/company-a/conf/common.parameters.json
```

And get this output

```
companyName:     MyCompany   // From common.parameters.json
environmentName: Production  // From common.parameters.json
environmentSize: Large       // From template default
outputFormat:    JSON        // From template default
```

And I can then deploy this template to Development with this command. Note here we are specifying two parameters files,
and when a parameter is repeated, it overrides any value in effect at that point.

```bash
az deployment group create --name MyDevelopmentDeployment \
                           --resource-group MyDevelopmentResourceGroup \
                           --template-file /path/to/baseline/deployments/test-template.bicep \
                           --parameters @/path/to/company-a/conf/common.parameters.json \
                           --parameters @/path/to/company-a/conf/development.parameters.json
```

And get this output

```
companyName:     MyCompany   // From common.parameters.json
environmentName: Development // From development.parameters.json (replaced value from common.parameters.json)
environmentSize: Small       // From development.parameters.json
outputFormat:    JSON        // From template default
```

So, this behavior is exactly what I want, clear and intuitive. Unfortunately, as of this date, the PowerShell equivalent
Azure Deployment functions do not support multiple parameters files. I can specify only one. So, to write the equivalent
logic, we need to combine the two parameters files when more than one is needed.

So, for the Production environment, we can do this and get the same output as with Azure CLI:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyProductionDeployment `
                              -ResourceGroupName MyProductionResourceGroup `
                              -TemplateFile \path\to\baseline\deployments\test-template.bicep `
                              -TemplateParameterFile \path\to\company-a\conf\common.parameters.json
```

However, for the Development environment, since we can't specify two files, I need to first combine the two JSON files
and create a new temp version (showing that here in pseudo-code) or merge them into some type of HashTable object which
can be passed in direct, without the need for the temp file.

```
Merge-ARMParametersFiles -Common   \path\to\company-a\conf\common.parameters.json `
                         -Override \path\to\company-a\conf\development.parameters.json `
                         -Result   \tmp\combined.parameters.json
```

**/tmp/combined.parameters.json** (if written to a temp file)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "comments": "Combined Result.",
  },
  "parameters": {
    "companyName": {
      "value": "CompanyA"
    },
    "environmentName": {
      "value": "Development"
    },
    "environmentSize": {
      "value": "Small"
    }
  }
}
```

Then allowing this for Development, again producing the same output as above for the Development Environment. Note the temp single combined JSON properties file.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyProductionDeployment `
                              -ResourceGroupName MyProductionResourceGroup `
                              -TemplateFile \path\to\baseline\deployments\test-template.bicep `
                              -TemplateParameterFile \tmp\combined.parameters.json
```

I have seen how to import the common.parameters.json. I've seen how to combine two hash tables. I can't seem to find
how to merge only the two properties maps within the two files and then write this out to a new file, so that's where
I'd like some help from a PowerShell expert. I think this problem is common enough, I was surprised to not find an
existing answer, so posting to help others as well as myself!

```
$CommonParameters   = Get-Content -Raw -Path \path\to\company-a\conf\common.parameters.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$OverrideParameters = Get-Content -Raw -Path \path\to\company-a\conf\development.parameters.json | ConvertFrom-Json

// How can I merge the two parameters sections, with any duplicates replaced with the override value, then write to
// the temp file?
```

Comment: If the Az CLI solution works for you, why not using th Az CLI task in Azure Devops ?

Answer (score 1):

To reduce your question to its essence:

- Given two PSCustomObject instances, merge and override some properties from one object into the other...

```
$override.parameters.psobject.Properties | foreach-object {
    $default.parameters | Add-Member `
        -NotePropertyName  $_.Name `
        -NotePropertyValue $_.Value `
        -Force;
}
```

Note that this *mutates* `$default` rather than returning a new object representing the merge.

Example usage:

```
# set up some test data

$default = @"
{
  "`$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "companyName": {
      "value": "CompanyA"
    },
    "environmentName": {
      "value": "Production"
    }
  }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$override = @"
{
  "`$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "comments": "Development Parameters.",
  },
  "parameters": {
    "environmentName": {
      "value": "Development"
    },
    "environmentSize": {
      "value": "Small"
    }
  }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json


# override the default values and add any extra parameters

write-host "before = ";
write-host ($default | ConvertTo-Json);
#{
#  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
#  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
#  "parameters": {
#    "companyName": {
#      "value": "CompanyA"
#    },
#    "environmentName": {
#      "value": "Production"
#    }
#  }
#}

$override.parameters.psobject.Properties | foreach-object {
    $default.parameters | Add-Member `
        -NotePropertyName  $_.Name `
        -NotePropertyValue $_.Value `
        -Force;
}

write-host "after = ";
write-host ($default | ConvertTo-Json);
#{
#  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
#  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
#  "parameters": {
#    "companyName": {
#      "value": "CompanyA"
#    },
#    "environmentName": {
#      "value": "Development"
#    },
#    "environmentSize": {
#      "value": "Small"
#    }
#  }
#}
```